# Permanently shrink leading columns of search results for Mendeley Desktop, Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mendeley

Whenever I search my library using command-F or directly in the search bar on the upper right, the results are formatted like so:

[image]

Needless to say the last column with all of the important information is quite difficult to read. I can of course manually resize the columns but these changes do not persist to the next search. Does anyone know a fix for this?

This is on version 1.19.3 on OS X Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've found is manually changing the view setting

1. Search
2. View -> Library as Citations
3. View -> Library as Table

It's clunky, but faster than re-sizing individual columns.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this appears to be a bug with no end user solution. It's been present in the Windows version of Mendeley for a long time now too (I'd guess at least a couple of years). Really, I'm very surprised the developers haven't fixed it yet given its visibility.

I think the best you can do is contact Mendeley support [here](https://service.elsevier.com/app/contact/supporthub/mendeley/session/L3RpbWUvMTU2NTY2NTkyMy9nZW4vMTU2NTY2NTkyMy9zaWQvZlVFMk4lN0UlN0VyWTlJVmNubXF0S21Zdm5LTUxHeFhOR2lRUEZMU2ZHJTdFcWF0OEF0NENrMEQxZk8zbEVoeGFvQlZSbFJPeFNIUk9zR3hsV1BWZVpvcnp6RFVTbmpMUEFTYVV3bkx1TXpabUpNdWdhSktFcXd3OG1MSU93JTIxJTIx/) or via social media and hope that if enough report it it will finally kick them into gear.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue. But one thing that I observed may contribute somehow to the solution.

1. On the 1st occurrence of wrong column size, you just have to resize columns to your optimal size manually
2. Searching again with new search query will work fine with columns having your specified column size ***until*** your search query (while still continue typing) starts mismatching with papers in your library leading to 0 search results
3. At this step, if you go for hitting backspace to correct your search query, the moment it again matches with your search query, it will again start showing you the wrong column size
4. Now to bring it back to correct column size again, delete that query completely and write it with the correct one (that yields at least 1 search results), it will again start showing correct column sizes as you specified earlier.

So it indicates the wrong column size is the reason for the wrong search query (seams very funny although but it is a bug I am seeing from a very long time that Mendeley has not yet resolved). As of today, I am using the latest Mendeley 1.19.5 and the issue persists.

I hope this may help you.